# Encontrar la primera fila de en una matriz que contenga todos los elementos positivos y la suma de estos elementos

Tags: python

Encontrar la primera fila de en una matriz que contenga todos los elementos positivos y la suma de estos elementos. Reducir todos los elementos de esta matriz a esta suma.

Para lograr lo requerido debería encontrar el array que tiene todos los elementos positivos, guradar el index de de este array y abrir otro bucle para sumarlos. Cómo podría hacerlo, es decir, cómo encontrar este array y guardarlo?

El objetivo es: obtener la fila de la matriz que tiene todos los elementos positivos, en este caso sería [7,2,3] y sumar estos elementos, que sería 12, y remplazar todos los elemetos de la matriz con el valor de la suma

Este es mi intento, de esta manera suma todos los elementos positivos.

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]

summ = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    pos = False
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] > 0:
            pos = True
            summ += matrix[i][j]

if pos:
    for i in range(len(matrix)):
        for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
            matrix[i][j] = summ
    print("Suma: ", summ)
    for i in matrix:
        print(" ",i)

else:
    print("No hay filas con todos elementos positivos.")
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la dificutad que tienes exactamente para poder ayudarte mejor?. Me serviria un ejemplo de que es lo que quieres obtener. Algo como esto: si ingreso la matriz  `[[-5,-6,2], [7,2,3], [8,4,-9]]` obtendría  `12 `. Además te recomiendo incluir el lugar del código donde no tienes claro como continuar o lo que sucede.

Comment: Si así: obtener la fila de la matriz que tiene todos los elementos positivos, en este caso sería  [7,2,3] y sumar estos elementos, que sería 12, y remplazar todos los elemetos de la matriz con el valor de la suma

Comment: Editalo en la pregunta directamente.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Podrías reducir tu función asi:

```
def suma_nasver(matriz):
    resultado = []
    suma = 0
    for arreglo in matriz:
        # Filtramos cada arreglo de la matriz para saber si contiene por lo menos
        # un elemento negativo, si no tiene ninguno se procede a hacer la suma
        elementos_negativos = list(filter(lambda elem: elem < 0, arreglo))
        if not elementos_negativos:
            # Asumo que es la suma de la primera ocurrencia
            suma = sum(arreglo)
            break
    # No es necesario un flag ya que se puede evaluar simplemente el resultado
    # de la suma
    if suma:
        # Si conocemos el largo de la matriz no es necesario iterarla nuevamente
        # para reemplazar los valores, solo usemos una lista vacia
        [resultado.append([suma]) for _ in range(len(matriz))]
    return resultado
```

Usando la función:

```
>>> suma_nasver([[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]])
[[12], [12], [12]]
>>> suma_nasver([[-5, -6, -2], [-6, -1, 0], [-4, -4, -1]])
[]
>>> suma_nasver([[-2], [3, 3, 3], [-4], [-9], [-4], [0]])
[[9], [9], [9], [9], [9], [9]]
```

Espero que con los comentarios haya quedado claro. Algunas notas:

- No es necesario hacer uso de la combinación `range()` y `len()` para iterar un objeto que de por si ya es iterable, simplemente pasalo al operador `in`:

  ```
  for arreglo in matriz:
      ...
  ```
- La función [`filter()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#filter) retorna una lista con los elementos que cumplen cierta condición, en `suma_nasver` la uso para saber si el arreglo contiene algún elemento negativo:

  ```
  elementos_negativos = filter(lambda elem: elem < 0, arreglo)
  ```
- Estoy usando una [lista de comprehensión](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) pero sin guardar el resultado ya que solo me interesa el procesamiento de esa parte del código (por eso también uso como variable a `_`, que nos dice que realmente no nos interesa su valor):

  ```
  [resultado.append([suma]) for _ in range(len(matriz))]
  ```
- No especificaste la versión de Python, pero la he modificado y probado para que funcione para Python 2 y 3

Comment: Pienso que debes cambiar `elementos_negativos = filter(lambda elem: elem < 0, arreglo)` por algo como: `no_positivos = filter(lambda elem: elem <= 0, arreglo)`, porque el cero no es un número positivo.

Answer (score 10):

Esta es la solución mas pythonica que se me ocurrió:

```
# Variable que guarda la suma de los numeros positivos por fila
suma_positivos = 0
# Recorremos la matriz fila por fila
for fila in matrix:
    # Verifica si todos los numeros de esta fila son positivos
    if all([numero > 0 for numero in fila]):
            suma_positivos =  sum(fila)
            # Se encontró la fila de positivos, entonces sal del ciclo                
            break

# Si se encontró la fila de positivos, entonces crea la nueva matriz
if suma_positivos:
    new_matrix = [[suma_positivos for value in matrix] for row in matrix]
```

**NOTAS**

`[numero > 0 for numero in fila]` es una [lista de comprensión](http://docs.python.org.ar/tutorial/3/datastructures.html#comprension-de-listas).

Lo que hace es que crear una lista nueva con valores booleanos (True/False)

Por ejemplo

```
[numero > 0 for numero in [1,2,3]]  # devuelve [True, True, True]
[numero > 0 for numero in [-1,2,3]] # devuelve [False, True, True]
```

[`all`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#all) es una función que retorna `True` si todos los elementos de la lista son verdaderos.

Por ejemplo:

```
all([True, True, True]) # devuelve True
all([False, True, True]) # devuelve False
```

Answer (score 9):

En mi opinión hay demasiados bucles "for" . Python contiene muchos elementos de programación funcional que pueden ayudar a resolver el problema de forma eficiente (o efectiva). En este caso:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
sumallpos = sum(next((x for x in matrix if min(x) > 0), [0]))
if sumallpos:
    matrix = [[sumallpos for x in y] for y in matrix]
else:
    print("No hay filas con todos elementos positivos.")
```

El uso de un `generator` junto con `next` asegura que no se analizan todas las filas de la matriz, puesto que se para en cuanto se encuentra alguna en la cual todos los elementos son mayores que cero `min(x) > 0`

La matriz resultante en el ejemplo:

```
[[12, 12, 12], [12, 12, 12], [12, 12, 12]]
```

La utilización de las `list comprehension` anidadas asegura que la matriz resultante tiene las mismas dimensiones que la original, puesto que se itera sobre los elementos originales (si es más efectivo iterar sobre los elementos o sobre algo como `range(len(x)` es harina de otro costal

Answer (score 7):

En resumidas cuentas:

```
matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]
sumas = [sum(xs) for xs in matrix if all(x > 0 for x in xs)]
if len(sumas) > 1:
    suma = sumas[0]
    print("Suma: ", suma)
    matrix = [[suma for _ in xs] for xs in matrix]
else:
    print("No hay filas con todos elementos positivos.")
```

Answer (score 7):

Se me ocurre lo siguiente (suponiendo que sea una matriz y todas las filas tengan el mismo número de columnas)

```
try:
   suma = sum(next(row for row in matrix if all(num>0 for num in row)))
except StopIteration as err:
   # No hay ninguna fila en que todos sean positivos
   pass
else:
   # Esto es posible suponiendo que todas las filas
   # tengan las mismas columnas
   matrix = [[suma]*len(matrix[0])]*len(matrix)
```

Answer (score 6):

creo que esto es lo que necesitas:

```
def reemplazar(mat,val):
    for r in range(len(mat)):
        if isinstance(mat[r],list):
            reemplazar(mat[r],val)
        else:
            mat[r]=val



matrix = [[-5, -6, 2], [7, 2, 3], [8, 4, -9]]

summ = 0
for i in range(len(matrix)):
    for j in range(len(matrix[i])):
        if matrix[i][j] >=0:
            summ += matrix[i][j]
        else:
            summ=0
            break #si tiene negativos, lo descarto
    if summ >0:
        print summ
        reemplazar(matrix,summ)
        print(matrix)
        break
else:
   print("No hay filas con todos elementos positivos.")
```

la función reemplazar en realmente "bruta", solo reemplaza todos los valores de la lista y las listas anidadas.

en resumen, iterar por cada lista (fila), y vas sumando los elementos de cada una, si una fila contiene un valor negativo, detienes la suma y continuas en la siguiente fila. si todas las filas tienen al menos un valor negativo, el else se ejecutará indicado la situación.

no recordé cómo hacer un continue al ciclo superior por lo que usé summ como bandera.

Answer (score 5):

yo no se python pero te ponder un pseudo code aver si te ayuda:

```
summ;
for a = 0; a < columnas.length; a++ {

  int filasCount = 0;
  summ = 0;

 for b = 0; b < filas.length; b++ {

     if array[a][b] > 0 {
      filasCount ++
      summ += matrix[a][b]
     }
 }
  //si lo de debajo se cumple quiere decir que todos son positivos 
  //en esa fila entoces rompemos el for (no se si en python se puede
  //romper el for) para no perder mas tiempo porque usted quiere la
  //primera fila que sea positiva y si tiene 1000 fila y resulta que la
  //primera es positiva no tiene que siguir buscando con lo que ahorra
  //tiempo

  if filasCount == filas.length (los numeros que tienes que mirar) {
    a = columnas.length + 1 (fuerza la salida del for superior)
  }

  //si no entra en el if quiere decir que ahi alguno negativo asi que el
  //contador se pondra a cero para la siguiente fila en la siguiente
  //vuelta junto con summ

 }
```

ahora que tienes el resultado que quieres en summ solo tienes que asignarlo a todo el array lo recorres y asignas el summ, si entiendo bien tu pregunta creo que con lo anterior es suficiente, pero tambien te comento que como python tiene montones de libreria quizas haya alguna especifica para lo que buscas

Por otro lado podrias usar algo asi para saltar las filas que tiene negativos.

```
for b = 0; b < filas.length; b++ {

     if array[a][b] > 0 {
      filasCount ++
      summ += matrix[a][b]
     }else{
     //si entra es que es un numero no valido para ti
     //asi que el entra y nosotros salimos pues esa fila no cumple con lo
     //que pedimos, pues ya uno no es valido

      b = filas.length +1
     }
 }
```